# Retrieve huge data table from MySQL within Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook, pymysql

I'm currently trying to fetch 100 million of rows from a MySQL table using the Jupyter Notebook. I have made some attempts with `pymysql.cursors` provided for open a MySQL connection. Actually I have tried to use batches in order to speed-up the query selection process cause it's a too much heavy operation to select all the rows together. Here below my test:

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='XXX',
                             user='XXX',
                             password='XXX',
                             db='XXX',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try: 
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        print(cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM `table`"))
        count = cursor.fetchone()[0]

        batch_size = 50

        for offset in xrange(0, count, batch_size):
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT %s OFFSET %s", 
                (batch_size, offset))
            for row in cursor:
                print(row)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

**For now the test should just print out each row (more or less not so worth), but the best solution in my opinion would be to store everything in a pandas dataframe.**

Unfortunately when I run it, I got this error:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>
> ```
>          print(cursor.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM `table`"))
> ```
>
> --->         count = cursor.fetchone()[0]
>
> ```
>          batch_size = 50
> ```
>
> KeyError: 0

Someone has an idea of what would be the problem?
Maybe the use of **chunksize** would be a better idea? 
Thanks in advance!

#### UPDATE

I have rewrite again the code without batch_size and storing the query result in a pandas dataframe. Finally it seems running but of course the execution time seems pretty much 'infinite' due to the fact that are 100mln rows as volume of data:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(user='XXX', password='XXX', database='XXX', host='XXX')

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        query = "SELECT * FROM `table`"

        cursor.execute(query)
        cursor.fetchall()

        df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

What should be a correct approach for speed-up the process? Maybe by passing as parameter `chunksize = 250`?
And also If I try to print the type of `df` then it ouputs that is a generator. Actually this **is not a dataframe**.

If I print `df` the output is:

```
<generator object _query_iterator at 0x11358be10>
```

How can I get the data in a dataframe format? Cause if I print the `fetch_all` command I can see the correct output selection of the query, so till that point everything works as expected.

If I try to use `Dataframe()` with the result of the `fetchAll` command I get:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

#### Another UPDATE

I was able to output the result by iterating `pd.read_sql` like this:

```
for chunk in pd.read_sql(query, connection, chunksize = 250):
        chunks.append(chunk)
    result = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
    print(type(result))
    #print(result)
```

And finally I got just one dataframe called `result`.

Now the questions are:

- Is it possible to query all the data without a LIMIT?
- What exactly influence the process benchmark?

Comment: Have you tried to just `cursor.fetchone()` and examine the result? Apparently it's a `dict`.

Comment: Hi @9000 I have tried it  with a print command and I get something like that: `{u'count(*)': 53885652}` that is the count of the rows from the mySQL table.

Comment: If I test ti again without [0] I got this: TypeError: an integer is required, and I supposed that it refers to offset.

Comment: `{u'count(*)': 53885652}` is a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries); you need `cursor.fetchone()['count(*)']` to access the value.

Comment: Okay, I think I got the point about dictionaries, and now if I print each row the ouptup seems also in that case like in a dictionary format. What if I want to convert the MySQL data in a pandas dataframe format instead? I have updated the question with a second attempt.

Comment: You can [convert the MySQL data in a pandas dataframe format](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+the+MySQL+data+in+a+pandas+dataframe+format).

Comment: I used pd.read_sql as explained in the doc, but this does not provide a dataframe result. If I print the the type it's a generator or something like that... I have updated the question with the second snippet.